# Creating a pipe from the inside of the python interpreter

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, pipe

sometimes i just want to quickly redirect a large output to an external program, supposing that in Python 3.x i have

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
```

how i can redirect the output of

```
>>> sys.modules.keys()
```

to a specific command or application ?

Comment: like? give us an example? and by the way, use ipython instead not the python interpreter itself, your life would be much easier

Comment: @Ali this is a pipe `cal | gedit` i want to do something like this `sys.modules.keys() | gedit`

Comment: @Ali I am also looking for a viable solution for applications that offer a built-in python interpreter and i can't use iPython.

Comment: @Ken the newer versions of iPython comes with a "backend" server that iPython interfaces with and it has exposed api to communicate with in your apps, does that help, if now, why can't you use iPython?

Comment: @Ali simply because i have to use the python interpreter built-in in the application. Many applications these days offers a built-in Python interpreter and i can't just use 1 random python interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do such things quite often, it could be useful to create a helper module which essentially does

```
def pipeinto(data, *prog):
    import subprocess
    sp = subprocess.Popen(prog, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    sp.stdin.write(str(data))
    sp.stdin.close()
    return sp
```

which enables you to do

```
pipeinto("\n".join(sys.modules.keys()), "gedit")
```

Comment: no built-in solution ? For example i find useful the `!` solution for the command line `ftp` client in linux which executes local commands .

Comment: @Ken: glglgl's answer using the `subprocess` module is, I think, the best generic solution you'll find. Any other approach is going to be specific to some IDE you could use to edit your Python programs. The standard interpreter doesn't have an `!` command or anything. It only does Python.